# Regular expression with only numbers, dots and minimum value

Tags: c#, regex, validation

Im trying to make a regular expression that accept only numbers, dots and that has minimum value and max value.

E.g:

- `1.000` - valid
- `100.000` - valid
- `100.000a` -not valid
- `.10` - not valid
- `100` - not valid

I have this, which works as i want with numbers and dots, only one thing is missing here, and that is minimum and maximum validation.

`@"^([+-]?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})*(?:\.\d+)*)$"`

PS:
Im using data annotations on .net core

**Update**

I have a javascript that separates users input in input field to thousand format like:

From: `1000000`

To: `1.000.000`

For better user experience.

But, the problem is the validation with data annotations.
With the RegularExpression i have above is working with the dots, i just need a minimum and maximum value.

I have tried with Range(min, max), but it recognise it as an invalid input because of the dots.

Regards

Comment: How about `bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(pattern, value) && value >= min && value <= max`

Comment: Oh, i forgot to mention that i am using data annotations on .net

Comment: If this is for a validation attribute have you considered just creating a new attribute with your requirements? They aren't hard to make and would be much more readable likely than a regex version of this (and would be easy to modify if your min and max change).

Comment: @Chris How can i make that?

Comment: @Muhaki: Its a bit hard to explain in comments but fortunately you can find help via google. Something like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224.aspx might get you started or there are probably questions on here related to custom validation attributes.

Comment: @Chris thanks, i will take a look :)

Comment: Check out [this](http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/) site that does it for integers. Then ask yourself, how much more complicated will it be for floats?

Comment: Two questions - your regex expects `,` as a thousands separator but your example has `.` - which is it? And - **What is the minimum value?** Your examples indicate that it's between one hundred and a thousand, but... If it **is** one thousand, simply changing the `*` to a `+` - like `@"^([+-]?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})+(?:\.\d+)?)$"` should do it for you. Finally an observation - your regex handles floats, but the decimal part (`(?:\.\d+)*`) allows formats like `1.22.333.444.555`. That can't be right... (?) (corrected in my "fixed" regex - `*` -> `?`)

Comment: @Rawling i did check that site out. But it gives an insanely long result :D

Comment: @ClasG Well, the separator should be as `.` and there should actually not be any floats. 
And the minimum value should be thousand yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your comment I assume this is what your after:

```
^[+-]?[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{3})+$
```

It matches a range of 1-3 digits (the first **not** being a `0`), then followed by at least one (no upper limit) sequence of `.` + three digits.

This will match any number larger than one thousand with `.` as thousand separators. And since your attempt allowed it, this also allows an optional sign in the beginning.

[See it in action here at regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%2b-%5d%3f%5b1-9%5d%5cd%7b0%2c2%7d%28%3f%3a%5c.%5cd%7b3%7d%29%2b%5cs&i=1.000%0d%0a100.000%0d%0a100.000a%0d%0a.10%0d%0a100%0d%0a%2b2.000%0d%0a-500.000%0d%0a&o=m). Note! I can't get `$` and multiline to work there so a `\s` is used instead to illustrate.

Answer (score -1):

Considering that after every number there is space character in the string 
This should do the job :

```
regex = @"[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,5}"
```

Update : 
As the obtained text will be numbers , so you could simply validate them for a range check .

For reference please have a look :[regex reference](https://regex101.com/r/T5jWJn/1)

Let me know , if it doesn't works

Comment: a) the strings in the OP don't have spaces in them. b) This doesn't look like it will solve the min/max validation.

Comment: Im not sure how this should fix the problem :)

Comment: Could you please post some sample text , why you wish to have a min/max number of characters validation set , when you could simply sort your number and get the required in range , still if needed let me know